# Is it necessary to encrypt client side activated Firebase Function Data?

Tags: firebase, security, encryption, google-cloud-functions

I use Flutter/Firestore/Cloud Functions.

Say I want to update a users balance via a transaction. I will call my Firebase function from the client with the help of Googles `cloud_functions` package:

```
Future updateBalance(amount)async{
    dynamic resp = await balanceUpdate.call(<String, dynamic>{
      'amount': amount
    });
    return resp.data;
 }
```

Is it possible for a attacker to middle man the function call and change the parameters? `amount` in this case. (ex: the attacker submits a $5 transaction and edits the call to the function changing it to $500).

If it isn't possible, should encryption be used anyways just to be safe, or it that not necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callable functions are just public HTTP functions that anyone can invoke using the [documented HTTP protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference). Anyone can invoke them and pass any parameters they want.

Additional encryption will not help here.  The API of the function is effectively public and easy to reverse engineer from the app's own code and behavior.  If you don't want someone invoking your function using arbitrary values, your function should have some code that validates the user and the parameters being passed.

Comment: Thanks, great to know. I will add validation to my functions to ensure misuse isn't possible along with a authentication check.